# Delete column if all cells after row 1 are blank

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with a bunch of headings but in some sheets the cells after the header row are blank.  I want to delete the column if all cells are blank except row 1 (header).

I have cobbled together the code below, however, it only retains the last array.  Where am I going wrong!!

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentSheetRange = currentSheet.getDataRange();
  var currentSheetVals = currentSheetRange.getValues();
  var currentSheetLC = currentSheet.getLastColumn();
  var currentSheetLR = currentSheet.getLastRow();
  var finalData = [];
  let finalDataVal
  var c;
  var r;

  for (r = 1; r < currentSheetLR; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < currentSheetLC; c++) {
      if (currentSheetVals[r][c] != "") {
        finalData.push(currentSheetVals[r][c]);
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log(finalData);

  var finalDataLength = finalData.length;
  var finalDataColLength = finalData[0].length;
  currentSheet.getRange(5, 1, finalData.length, finalData[0].length).setValues(finalData);

}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who has a solution!

Comment: do you want to delete columns or rows ?

Comment: Columns please.

Comment: You code does not do nothing related to deleting columns, I provided an answer with a sample how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To delete all empty columns (headers excluded):

- Retrieve the data range without headers
- Loop through each of the columns and use `join()` to verify either all column entries are empty
- Use `deleteColumn()` to delete empty columns
- Loop backwards to make sure that the deletion of columns does not mess up your column positions

**Sample:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentSheetLC = currentSheet.getLastColumn();
  var currentSheetLR = currentSheet.getLastRow();
  var SheetRangeWithoutHeaders = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentSheetLR- 1, currentSheetLC);
  var currentSheetVals = SheetRangeWithoutHeaders.getValues();
  var c;
    
  for (c = currentSheetLC; c > 0; c--) {
    var columnData = currentSheetVals.map(row=>row[c-1]);
    console.log("columnData: " + columnData);
    if(columnData.join("") ==""){
      console.log("Column is empty");
      currentSheet.deleteColumn(c);
    }
  }
}
```

**References:**

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [deleteColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumncolumnposition)